# Ping the network inside docker container from outside on the same host machine

Tags: docker, network-programming, sctp

I was following the setup for open5gs code [here](https://docs.srsran.com/projects/project/en/latest/tutorials/source/srsUE/source/index.html#open5gs-core)

Essentially I expose a sctp port 38412 from inside the container and fail to ping or connect to network from the same host machine the container is running on (single machine).

```
services:
  5gc:
    container_name: open5gs_5gc
    build:
      context: open5gs
      target: open5gs
      args:
        OS_VERSION: "22.04"
        OPEN5GS_VERSION: "v2.6.1"
    env_file:
      - ${OPEN_5GS_ENV_FILE:-open5gs/open5gs.env}
    privileged: true
    ports:
      - "3000:3000/tcp"
      # Uncomment port to use the 5gc from outside the docker network
      - "38412:38412/sctp"
    command: 5gc -c open5gs-5gc.yml
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "nc -z 127.0.0.20 7777"]
      interval: 3s
      timeout: 1s
      retries: 60
    networks:
      ran:
        ipv4_address: ${OPEN5GS_IP:-10.53.1.2}
```

From inside the container, the ping works.

```
❯ docker exec -it open5gs_5gc bash
root@15e61fd8c4b3:/open5gs# ping 10.53.1.1
PING 10.53.1.1 (10.53.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.53.1.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.112 ms
64 bytes from 10.53.1.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.040 ms
64 bytes from 10.53.1.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.041 ms
^C
--- 10.53.1.1 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2051ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.040/0.064/0.112/0.033 ms
```

From the host outside of the container, it doesn't:

```
❯ ping -c 4 10.53.1.2
PING 10.53.1.2 (10.53.1.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 10.53.1.1 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.53.1.1 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.53.1.1 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.53.1.1 icmp_seq=4 Destination Host Unreachable

--- 10.53.1.2 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 0 received, +4 errors, 100% packet loss, time 3049ms
pipe 4
```

The same error occurs after `docker network prune` and rebuilding docker compose.

This is an issue I raised for srsRAN_Project [here](https://github.com/srsran/srsRAN_Project/issues/500). More details can be found in there.

**UPDATE:**
The high-level idea is to connect the open5gs part above to a `gnb` that was compiled on host-machine via `sudo ./gnb -c gnb_zmq.yaml`

The config `gnb_zmq.yaml` is as follows:

```
# This configuration file example shows how to configure the srsRAN Project gNB to allow srsUE to connect to it. 
# This specific example uses ZMQ in place of a USRP for the RF-frontend, and creates an FDD cell with 10 MHz bandwidth. 
# To run the srsRAN Project gNB with this config, use the following command: 
#   sudo ./gnb -c gnb_zmq.yaml

amf:
  addr: 10.53.1.2                  # The address or hostname of the AMF.
  bind_addr: 10.53.1.1             # A local IP that the gNB binds to for traffic from the AMF.
...
```

Comment: The container `ipv4_address:` is a Docker-internal address (and you should pretty much never need to set it).  What part of your application code sends and receives these ICMP packets; why is `ping` an important use case?

Comment: @DavidMaze I added more information above - does that answer your question? There's also graphical info [here](https://docs.srsran.com/projects/project/en/latest/tutorials/source/srsUE/source/index.html#zeromq-based-setup)

Comment: Usually in Docker you will want to set `bind_addr: 0.0.0.0` to listen on "all interfaces"; that will make it accessible via normal container networking and from the host via published `ports:`.  You do not need to manually set `ipv4_address:`.